# Header 'RevenueCat-Swift.h' not found & Could not build Objective-C module 'RevenueCat'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, revenuecat

I integrated RevenueCat into an app written in Swift and SwiftUI. It worked all well until now.
All of the sudden Xcode throws these two errors when building the app:

> Could not build Objective-C module 'RevenueCat'

At the import RevenueCat statement

> Header 'RevenueCat-Swift.h' not found

In a modul.modulemap

The Content of the modulemap is as followed.

```
framework module RevenueCat {
  umbrella header "RevenueCat-umbrella.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }

}
 

module RevenueCat.Swift {
    header "RevenueCat-Swift.h"
    requires objc
}
```

The weird thing is, that after rebuilding the app once or twice, the errors disappear.
However, if I try to archive the app, they pop up every time and prevent Xcode from archiving the Build.

I updated to the lates Xcode version some days ago, beside that there's nothing special that could point to the start of the problem.

Any Ideas on that?

Comment: I've had this happen too and think it's probably just an Xcode bug. As long as you can run the app and the errors disappear I would ignore it for now. 

As far as archiving are you running it on the "Any iOS Device" device option? It won't work if not.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on the "Any iOS Device", it worked all well for the last couple of Weeks before the bug or whatever it is entered the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Somehow my pods framework ended as a target in my build scheme… 
I don’t know when that happened but it was not intended and removing it solved the issue.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing using the Swift Package Manager.  I had a lot of Swift issues with our Objective C Project, especially with their Example Swift app.  Ultimately went with Glassfy which is much easier to setup and use.  Also, Glassfy seems to be more Objective C friendly...